# Multiple call to back-end (By curresponding backbone model) on clicking on pie-legend highcharts

Tags: backbone.js, highcharts

I am using a highchart pie-legend graph in a backbone application.If i click on a portion of pie chart,it calls back-end for only 1 time. If I click again on a portion without getting chart redrawn,even then only 1 call to back end is there. But if I cause chart to be redrawn by clicking on a legend and then I click on a portion of pie-chart, it calls two times for back end. I can see it on console of firebug debugger. And if I again make chart to be redrawn by any change, calls to the back-end increase accordingly. How can I restrict these unwanted multiple calls on clicking pie-legend chart.
The click on legent is also captured and kept. And when I click on pie chart,it accumulates the number of clicks and send multiple calls to back-end through model. 
Thanks is advance.

The code is as follows:

```js
chart: {
  backgroundColor: null,
  events:{
   redraw: function() {
    var dataObj = this.series[0].data;
    $.each(dataObj, function( index ) {
     var pathObj = dataObj[index].graphic.element;
     pathObj['contentValue']=dataObj[index].name;
     $(pathObj).popoverClosable({
      container:'div#chart-donut',
      html: true,
      trigger:'click',
      placement: 'top',
      content:'<div class="popover-dummy"></div>'
     });
     $(pathObj).on('click', function () {
      //render the corresponding popover content
      var spinner = new Spinner().spin();
      $('div.popover-dummy').html(spinner.el);
      var contentCategory=pathObj.point.name;
      var model = Backbone.model;
      if(!that.brandDetailsPopoverView || that.brandDetailsPopoverView == null){
       that.brandDetailsPopoverView = new BrandDetailsPopoverView({model:model,brandName:that.selectedBrandName,topicId:that.curTopicId,brandId:that.brandId,contentCategory:contentCategory,groupId: that.selectedGroupId,el:"#discover-popover-content"});
      }
      that.brandDetailsPopoverView.render(contentCategory);
      $('div.popover-dummy').html($('#discover-popover-content').html());
     });
    });
   }
    },
    margin: [10,20,10,10]
 },
```

Comment: Probably a zombie view but without any code to illustrate your question, that's really hard to solve

Comment: Ohhh,sorry...I will add the snippet as soon as I have access to my code :-) Thanks :-)

Comment: It's called multiple times, because on each redraw you are adding `$(pathObj).on('click', function () { ... });` new click callback? Events add only once - on chart's load.

Comment: I could not add the snapshot of chart as I do not have privilege to do so. Thanks.

Comment: @PawełFus: Thanks a lot....I changed the code,now no matter howmany times redraw is called,events are getting bound only once. Thanks :-)